# Add line with JS ans return Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to add on line ( 2 fields) a each click for my inputs.
each line must be with unique Id .

So , I need after that to save these lines in a object like this {key:value, key:value, key:value} who key is the value of the input time and value is the value of input intensity.
For example { 10:50, 20:80, 50:40, ....}

I made a JsFiddle if someone can help me.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianczech/a5op8zk6/16/)

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="app">
<v-app >
<p>Select your infos</p>
<div class="infos" >
  <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-text-field              
                     label="time"
                     class="input"
                     type="number"
                     v-model="array.time"               
              ></v-text-field>
  <v-divider></v-divider>     
                <v-text-field
                     label="intensity"
                     class="input"
                     type="number"
                     v-model="array.intensity"
              ></v-text-field> 
         <v-btn>add Line</v-btn>
</div>         
        </v-app>
</div>
```

```
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {

  // #1 method to add line
  // # method to console an object like { time:intensity, time:intensity, time:intensity,... } so for example { 10:50, 20:80, 50:40, ....}

  },
  data() {
    return {
        array: [],

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Is that what you want?
https://jsfiddle.net/kdydesign30/fvyxqdoe/4/

Comment: Yes it look like I want, I test it tomorrow and I tell you. D'où you know how return an object like I need?

Comment: In order to return it as an object, you have to process the example 'fields' through 'computed'.

Comment: @Sébastian, can you please create a separate question for 2d array for loop for dynamic addition and deletion of row lines

Comment: I had a problem with the 2d array post so I delete it. Do you have a idea about the returning object @chans

Comment: Yes I already shared the code pen, does that resolved your issue ??

Comment: sorry , I don't see it